# Changing position on a 2D plane

Tags: javascript

I am writing a small game in javascript. I am trying to move a character around as if looking down from above. It's been a while since I have done any basic maths and I can't get some of my positioning to work properly. I want to move a number of steps at a given angle. The input is generated by the program based on user key presses and events from my model.

I have the following code

```
var xPos = 0, yPos = 0, angle = 45, distance = 1;

var yDelta = Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance,
    xDelta = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(distance, 2) - Math.pow(yDelta, 2));
yPos += yDelta;
xPos += xDelta;
```

My test cases are

- at 45 degrees take 1 step forward expects (0.7071, 0.7071) and is (0.7071, 0.7071)
- at 45 degrees take 1 step backwards expects (-0.7071, -0.7071), but is (0.7071, -0.2928)

I can't see what is wrong with my algorithm for moving. As far as I can see the maths is correct. Is there an obvious mistake I am making? Or is there a simpler approach I could take?

Comment: what are you trying to do ? what is the purpose of your game ?

Comment: @sora I am trying to move a character around as if looking down from above

Comment: are you using html5 canvas ? in what position you want to move the character ? are you using user input ?

Comment: @sora I want to move the character a distance at an angle from a specified position. I am using this to update the model, which will be reflected in the UI. This makes it independent of any UI technology, such as canvas and makes it easily unit testable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to compute `xDelta` as

```
xDelta = Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance;
```

and for backwards you should subtract (not add) xDelta and yDelta to position.